# Accessing arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, raphael

I'm using the Raphaël framework to draw dynamic shapes (which make them clickeable, you can make them glow...).

I can't access the array correctly.

I've created an array :

```
var siegeurs = { 

  1 : [{           
          "Nom" : "User1",
          "Photo" : "url"
            }],
  2 : [{
          "Nom" : "User2",
          "Photo" : "url"
            }],
  3 : [{     
          "Nom" : "User3",
          "Photo" : "url"
            }],
  4 : [{       
          "Nom" : "User4",
          "Photo" : "url"
            }],
  5 : [{        
          "Nom" : "User5",
          "Photo" : "url"
            }]
};
```

These are the shapes that the framework draw :

```
sieges["1"] = assembly.path("M236.51 ... 108");
sieges["2"] = assembly.path("M483.51 ... 71");
sieges["3"] = assembly.path("M427.51 ... 272");
sieges["4"] = assembly.path("M135.51 ... 348");
sieges["5"] = assembly.path("M617.51 ... 413");
```

They are like object so you can interact with them.

This is the loop :

```
for(var siegeNum in sieges) {
(function (siege) {
    siege.attr(style); //apply style to shapes

    siege[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        siege.animate(hoverStyle, animationSpeed); //add hoverstyle when hovered

        //The line I can't figure out
        document.getElementById("textelement").innerHTML = siegeurs[siegeNum]["Nom"]; 
        //The line I can't figure out


    }, true);

    siege[0].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
      siege.animate(style, animationSpeed);
      document.getElementById("textelement").innerHTML = baseTxt;
    }, true);

})
(sieges[siegeNum]);
}
```

`textelement` is a basic text I try to modify when a shape is hovered. 
Actually, when I hover a shape, the text goes to "undefined".

I tried to do this way just to check :

```
document.getElementById("textelement").innerHTML = siegeurs[siegeNum];
```

But when I hover, the text goes to [object Object].

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each value in your `siegeurs` object is an array, so the needed inner property `"Nom"` should be accessed as:

```
...
document.getElementById("textelement").innerHTML = siegeurs[siegeNum][0]["Nom"];
```

Comment: It works ! But why do we have to put the [0] in between [siegeNum] and ["Nom"] and not just after siegeurs ?

Comment: Since arrays in JavaScript are treated as objects too, you might add as well this alternative `siegeurs[siegeNum][0].Nom`